# FBWebDilaog shared URL redirecting to app

Tags: facebook

I am using FBWebDialog (supported in the new facebook 3.2 SDK) to share on facebook in from my  ios application. I am setting a youtube link for the link parameter passed in the arguments
 for the FBWebDialog. It shares the link but on tapping the link from the facebook account logged in from the facebook app on the iOS device redirects me to the app, if the app is present in the device. If the app is not found on the device it directs me to itunes page of my app. This is an anomalous behavior as the it should redirect me to youtube link. However, if I login to the facebook account on a PC and click the shared link it redirects me to youtube link.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your App Dashboard settings: Basic > Native iOS App, then turn the Deep Linking to Disabled.

You want to turn off deep linking back to your app. This will however, turn deep linking off for all links from your app.